# Windows built Docker Image doesn't work in Mac M1

Tags: macos, dockerfile, docker-image

With the following lines, I've made a Docker Image. It works on Windows and Linux. But my friend cannot open it on his Mac M1 OS. Here is the content of docker yaml file:

```
FROM python:3.8.12-slim
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8501
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Please let me know what's wrong here and why he couldn't open the image which has been built from these lines?

I just guess that I should somehow get rid of 'pip' and replace it with 'brew'. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

The "3.8.12-slim" image does not support mac m1 architecture. Try an image that has "linux/arm64/v8" OS support. For example "3.8.16-slim-buster" or even newer version.